AWS Amplify - NUXT 3 deploy
I am trying to deploy a NUXT 3 project with SSG. I got a deploy issue.
My amplify.yml:
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - nvm use 18 && node --version
        - npm install -g pnpm
        - pnpm install
    build:
      commands:
        - pnpm run generate
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: ".output/public/"
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*

And here is there error at deploy :
2024-04-05T08:18:46.618Z [ERROR]: !!! CustomerError: Failed to find the deploy-manifest.json file in the build output. Please verify that it exists within the "baseDirectory" specified in your buildSpec. If it's not there, we will also check the .amplify-hosting directory as a fallback. When using a framework adapter for hosting on Amplify, double-check that the adapter settings are correct.

Any idea ?
Aws should not create the file deploy-manifest.json ?

I faced this error too and it was because initially in the same Amplify app I had a successful build with a nuxt build for a SSR app. But afterwards I switched to a static website with nuxt generate which led to this error.
Exact words from the support:
"Since Amplify detected this App as SSR, it updated the platform to WEB_COMPUTE, which is the compute engine for Amplify SSR Apps.
I can see that you have subsequently updated the buildSpec to deploy a static Nuxt App, however the platform is still configured to WEB_COMPUTE. This build is failing during deployment because Amplify expects additional SSR related artifacts for SSR deployments that are not present since the build commands are generating a static App."
I fixed it with the following CLI command:
aws amplify update-app --app-id <app-id> --platform WEB --region <region>
Hope this helps!

Hey the deploy works ! but I have the same issue as in "build" mode. I get a 502 error. did you faced this error too ?

Okay, I added a redirection / to index.html (200), and it works !
